# Assigning the value returned by a function to a variable in Python

Tags: python

I began coding in Python recently and encountered a problem assigning the value returned by a function to a variable.

```
class Combolock:
    def _init_(self,num1,num2,num3):
        self.x = [num1,num2,num3]
    def next(self, state):
        print "Enter combination"
        combo = raw_input(">")
        if combo == self.x[state]:
            print "Correct"
            return 1
        else:
            print "Wrong"
            return 0
    def lock(self):
        currentState = 0
        while currentState < 2:
            temp = next(currentState)
            if temp == 1:
                currentState = currentState + 1
            else:
                currentState = 99
                print "ALARM"
```

When I call the lock function, I get an error at the line

```
temp = next(currentState)
```

saying that an int object is not an iterator.

Answer (score 8):

You should use `self.next(currentState)`, as you want the `next` method in the class scope.

The function `next` is global and `next(obj)` works only if `obj` is an [iterator](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types).
You might want to have a look at the [yield statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#yield) in the python documentation.

Answer (score 4):

As Andrea (+1) pointed it out you need to tell python you want to call next() method on self object, so you need to call it `self.next(currentState)`.

Also, note, that you have defined incorrect initializer (aka. constructor). You have to use double underscores:

```
__init__(...
```

instead of:

```
_init_(...
```

otherwise it is just a method - not called while object creataion.

Answer (score 0):

Use self.next(currentState) instead, otherwise it's referring to the next() method of the iterator, not your class

Answer (score 0):

The error means just what it says.  When you use `next(iterable)`, [`next`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next) tries to call the `iterable`'s `next` *method*.  However, when you do `dir(0)`:

```
['__abs__',
 # ... snip ...
 '__xor__',
 'bit_length',
 'conjugate',
 'denominator',
 'imag',
 'numerator',
 'real']
```

As you can see, there is no `next` method on an integer.

If you are trying to call your own `next` method, then you need to use `self.next` not `next`.  [`next`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#next) is a builtin function that calls the `next` method of an iterator to let you do things like this:

```
 for something in my_iterator:
     print something
```

Try:

```
temp = self.next(currentState)
```